# Построение связей между 3 таблицами

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть 3 таблицы. Раздел, Тип, Продукт. Нужно построить связи между этими таблицами.
Условия: Тип может быть в разных разделах, Продукт может быть в нескольких типах. Должно быть поле типа флажка показывать товар у этого типа или нет, и это поле зависит от того, в каком разделе лежит тип.

---

Есть 2 варианта. Не могу выбрать какой лучше и правильнее.

1 Вариант: Объединить Раздел и Тип связью многие-ко-многим в таблице (Раздел_Тип), и Раздел_Тип объединить с Продуктом (Раздел_Тип_Продукт).

Таким образом атрибуты в таблице Раздел_Тип: 
pk_id - первичный ключ Раздел_Тип 
razdel_id - id Раздела 
type_id - id Типа

Атрибуты в Раздел_Тип_Продукт: 
pk_id - первичный ключи таблицы Раздел_Тип_Продукт 
razdel_type_pk_id - внешний ключ таблицы Раздел_Тип 
product_id - id Продукта 
show - Показывать товар или не показывать.

---

2 Вариант: Это тупо запихнуть связи между Разделом, типом и продуктом в одну таблицу
Таким образом атрибуты данной таблицы будут следующими: 
pk_id - первичный ключ 
razdel_id - id Раздела 
type_id - id Типа 
product_id - id Продукта 
show - Показывать товар или не показывать

---

Какой из вариантов правильнее и почему ?

Comment: *Условия: Тип может быть в разных разделах, Продукт может быть в нескольких типах.* Т.е. две связи много-ко-много. *Не могу выбрать какой лучше и правильнее* Если верить описанию - никакой.

Comment: *и Раздел_Тип объединить с Продуктом (Раздел_Тип_Продукт).* В условии продукт может быть просто "в нескольких типах", а не иметь тип, принадлежащий определённому разделу. *запихнуть связи между Разделом, типом и продуктом в одну таблицу* И получить денормализацию. Плюс  - где будете хранить связь типа и раздела, если для этой пары нет товара?